# react query lazy loaded properties of an object

Tags: react-query

I have an api that returns the properties I need, like this:

```js
fetchPost(1, ['title', 'content'])
// => { id: 1, title: 'hello', content: 'world!' }
fetchPost(1, ['title', 'author'])
// => { id: 1, title: 'hello', author: 'A' }
```

I defined two hooks for react query:

```js
function usePostTitleAndContent(id) {
  return useQuery(['post', id], async () => fetchPost(id, ['title', 'content']))
}

function usePostTitleAndAuthor(id) {
  return useQuery(['post', id], async () => fetchPost(id, ['title', 'author']))
}
```

I hope that after each query is executed, the results can be merged into the same cache object, and if the required properties already exist, the cached results will be returned directly, but my writing method above cannot do this, Can you give me any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

different query functions that return different data should have different keys. In your case, that would be:

```
function usePostTitleAndContent(id) {
  return useQuery(['post', id, 'content'], async () => fetchPost(id, ['title', 'content']))
}

function usePostTitleAndAuthor(id) {
  return useQuery(['post', id, 'author'], async () => fetchPost(id, ['title', 'author']))
}
```

otherwise, the two fetch functions would write to the same cache entry and thus overwrite each other.